# pass variable from livewire view to nested view

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a livewire parent view which opens a child modal and I would like to pass a variable from parent to child.
The code I have so far in parent:`<livewire:child-view :year="2023"/>` 
I have a controller which outputs `public function mount($year)` correctly.
 But from `child-view` output `{{ $year }}` I get `Undefined variable $year`

Q: what is the best way to pass `:year` so I can output the string inside `child-view.blade.php`

Incase anyone else has a similar issue I realized I had to use controllers `public function render()` to send the variable back into `child-view`

Answer (score 1):

In the parent blade file:

```
<livewire:child-view :year="2023"/>
```

In the child controller:

```
public $year;
function mount($year){
  $this->year = $year
}
```

In the child blade you can use $year

---

Another way to change or pass a param into other livewire components is using "dispatch" and "on" events in livewire 3 or "emit" and "on" in version 2

In parent controller

```
public function showModal()
{
  // ...
 
  $this->dispatch('show-modal', year: $post->year); 
}
```

In child controller:

```
public $year;
#[On('show-modal')] 
public function handleShowModalInChild($year)
{
    // some actions to show modal
    $this->year = $year
}
```

After that you can use $year in blade file

---

You can learn all about events in this link:
https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/events

Comment: I was hoping to pass the var to child directly without involving the controller